# PHP access to object - advanced

Tags: php, object

this is var_dump for my object

```
object(HapiClient\Hal\Resource)[25]
  private 'state' => 
    array (size=5)
      'reference' => string '7498ff04-240c-11e6-9f09-000000000000' (length=36)
      'state' => string 'open.running' (length=12)
      'started' => boolean true
      'dateCreated' => string '2016-05-27T13:10:59.589+0000' (length=28)
      'paymentScheme' => string 'SEPA.DIRECT_DEBIT.CORE' (length=22)
  private 'links' => 
    array (size=6)
      'self' => 
        object(HapiClient\Hal\Link)[59]
          private 'href' => string 'INFORMATION' (length=94)
          private 'templated' => null
```

...

all of this = $res;

how to get access to this :

```
private 'href' => string 'INFORMATION' (length=94)
```

OR

```
 'state' => string 'open.running' (length=12)
```

Comment: the only way to access to a private propriety outside the class is with [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/it/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php)

Comment: @Federico - or by using methods provided by the class itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That package provides some public accessor methods, as described here:
https://github.com/SlimPay/hapiclient-php/tree/master/src/Hal

In your case, to access the "state", you would use

```
$state = $res->getState()['state'];
```

and to get the "href" you would use

```
$href = $res->getLink('self')->getHref();
```

Comment: you mean [`getState`](https://github.com/SlimPay/hapiclient-php/blob/master/src/Hal/Resource.php#L41) and `getLink('self')`